# Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 secure boot

Tags: boot, server, uefi

I have a servers **Dell server R650**, which has been running Ubuntu 18.04 for couple of years with secure boot enabled.
When attempting to upgrade it to Ubuntu 20.04 using official ISO image 20.04.6  I encountered the following issue.

After booting into Ubuntu 20.04 once, subsequent attempts to boot into both Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04 with secure boot enabled are not successful.

For Ubuntu 18 I got

```
sbat.c:120:verify_single_entry() component sbat has a matching SBAT variable entry, verifying
sbat.c:120:verify_single_entry() component grub has a matching SBAT variable entry, verifying
sbat.c:131:verify_single_entry() component grub, generation 1, was revoked by SbatLevel variable
sbat.c:182:verify_sbat_helper() finished verifying SBAT data: Security Policy Violation
Verification failed: Security Policy Violation
Failed to load image: Security Policy Violation
```

For Ubuntu 20, the situation is different.

```
sbat.c:125:verify_single_entry() component sbat has a matching SBAT variable entry, verifying
sbat.c:191:verify_sbat_helper() finished verifying SBAT data: Success
shim.c:1740:efi_main() SBAT self-check succeeded
```

But server is “stuck” for 10 minutes or so and then rebooting itself.

All boots are made from official and unmodified Ubuntu ISO images using IDRAC virtual media.

The following steps were taken (one by one and all together), but still cannot boot (with secure boot)

- Platform Key (PK) –> Restore Default Platform Key
- Key Exchange Key (KEK) Database -> Restore Default KEK Database
- Authorized Signature Database (db) -> Restore default
- Restore Default Policy Entries (PK, KEK, db and dbx)
- BIOS reset to default

This server system certified with Ubuntu (20.04/22.04) - https://ubuntu.com/certified/202105-29054

Any help to get Ubuntu 20.04 (and Ubuntu 18.04) secure boot possible?

Comment: Do you still have access to the install media, and are able to open a remote console to the install ISO environment via IPMI / Redfish / iDRAC web?  If you have access to the rescue environment provided by the ISO, I may have a possible solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm inquiring about a broader scenario. I'm not just concerned about a single server; rather, I have a potential issue across thousands of them. I need to comprehend the root cause and determine how to prevent it.

I looked your answers in another cases - bad shim signature, where grub loader and shim are using different signature. Even (if) this is my case, i see no way to solve it in my state, can you advise?

Comment: What I was hoping is that once you have access to and boot into the rescue environment, you should be able to mount the installed disks, and check on the signatures of the booting kernels. In case the booting kernel needs to be updated, the rescue environment allows you to do that too, via appropriately setting up mounts and then using `chroot`. This investigation should allow you to change your install process to factor in the issues with this one install AND/OR alter your migration plans drastically. (Been there, with 1.7K servers needing updates ...)

Answer (score 0):

Compiling those two posts:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+source/mokutil/+bug/2015664
- https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sbat-revocations-boot-process/34996

I've got temporary solution like:

1. Turn SecureBoot OFF
2. Boot Ubuntu 18 (installed or live), get into a shell and update (install) mokutil (mokutil must be at least 0.6.0-2, Ubuntu 18 standard repository can be used)
3. Run mokutil and delete SBAT policy records.

```
mokutil --set-sbat-policy delete
```

4. Boot Ubuntu 20.04 (or any above) and stop on grub menu (it will delete SBAT records)
5. Halt system and turn Secure Boot ON in BIOS.
6. Boot Ubuntu 18 ISO in Secure Boot ON mode.